# Why are Oyster Pearl's transactions clumping like this, and not getting confirmed? Is this an issue with the tip selection algo?

Tags: tangle, iota-network

[image: Oyster Pearl]

It appears that Oyster Pearl, a data transmission service built on the tangle, has launched their testnet and is submitting transactions to IOTA tangle live and tagging them (see above image).

As we can see, the transactions are heavily clumped and hardly any are getting confirmed, if any at all, creating massive amounts of tips and flooding the tangle.

Since they are processing data and not sending iota currency, they don't even necessarily need confirmations (am I correct here?).

Is this an issue for the tangle, and the tip selection algorithm they've decided to use? Is this why we are seeing high TPS (currently ~20-40) but low CTPS (~.5-2)?